# BIP32 Extended Public Key Generate Ethereum Address

Tags: addresses, nodejs, public-key, account-generation

[image]

BIP32 Extended Public Key How can I generate an address with node js?
Is something like this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const hdwallet =  () => {
  let hdnode = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromExtendedKey(
    "xpub6EU9wCZtFWLvSuqz6Apd4xWjx2LWToJhAaswLRvb9XEKcRS9p4f63bGNhVboDqxDfERqGtA3gkxFj6CYynxXKmsrkV8HEjcVcGu4orqxmzQ",
    "m/44'/60'/0'/0"
  );
  let wallet = hdnode.derivePath("0");
  console.log(wallet.address);
};

hdwallet();
```

finding a solution
again thank you everyone